# Django 'module' object has no attribute ALL_FIELDS

Tags: python, django, zinnia

The same code base in production is giving me the following error in my server logs. The issue seems to be with the **zinnia blog app** that I use within my Django CMS. What is this error and how do I resolve?

I have reinstall this zinnia and still get the error, strange thing is that the issue does not appear on my local machine using the same database.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in handle_uncaught_exception
if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/srv/project/cherry/cherry/core/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
admin.autodiscover()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 29, in autodiscover
import_module('%s.admin' % app)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
 __import__(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zinnia/admin/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from zinnia.admin.entry import EntryAdmin
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zinnia/admin/entry.py", line 25, in <module>
from zinnia.admin.forms import EntryAdminForm
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zinnia/admin/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
class CategoryAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zinnia/admin/forms.py", line 44, in CategoryAdminForm
class Meta:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zinnia/admin/forms.py", line 49, in Meta
fields = forms.ALL_FIELDS
**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ALL_FIELDS'**
```

**File on server from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zinnia/admin/forms.py:**

```
"""Forms for Zinnia admin"""
from django import forms
from django.db.models import ManyToOneRel
from django.db.models import ManyToManyRel
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper

from mptt.forms import TreeNodeChoiceField

from zinnia.models.entry import Entry
from zinnia.models.category import Category
from zinnia.admin.widgets import MPTTFilteredSelectMultiple
from zinnia.admin.fields import MPTTModelMultipleChoiceField


class CategoryAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for Category's Admin.
    """
    parent = TreeNodeChoiceField(
        label=_('Parent category'),
        level_indicator='|--', required=False,
        empty_label=_('No parent category'),
        queryset=Category.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CategoryAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        rel = ManyToOneRel(Category._meta.get_field('tree_id'),
                           Category, 'id')
        self.fields['parent'].widget = RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(
            self.fields['parent'].widget, rel, self.admin_site)

    def clean_parent(self):
        """
        Check if category parent is not selfish.
        """
        data = self.cleaned_data['parent']
        if data == self.instance:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                _('A category cannot be parent of itself.'))
        return data

    class Meta:
        """
        CategoryAdminForm's Meta.
        """
        model = Category
        fields = forms.ALL_FIELDS



class EntryAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for Entry's Admin.
    """
    categories = MPTTModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label=_('Categories'), required=False,
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
        widget=MPTTFilteredSelectMultiple(_('categories'), False,
                                          attrs={'rows': '10'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EntryAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        rel = ManyToManyRel(Category, 'id')
        self.fields['categories'].widget = RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(
            self.fields['categories'].widget, rel, self.admin_site)
        self.fields['sites'].initial = [Site.objects.get_current()]

    class Meta:
        """
        EntryAdminForm's Meta.
        """
        model = Entry
        fields = forms.ALL_FIELDS
```

**Shell:**

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06)                                                                                                                 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2                                                                                                                                         
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
>>> import django                                                                                                                                             
>>> django.VERSION                                                                                                                                            
(1, 5, 1, 'final', 0)                                                                                     
>>> from django.forms import ALL_FIELDS                                                                                                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                            
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                         
ImportError: cannot import name ALL_FIELDS                                                                                                                    
>>>
```

Comment: Can you show us your zinnia app forms.py file? Also, what version of django have you installed on the server? It seems it's not the same as your local machine's

Comment: I have Django 1.5.5 installed same as local which works. The zinnia form file is unchanged from install pip intsall django-blog-zinnia used

Comment: https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/blob/develop/zinnia/admin/forms.py

Comment: ALL_FIELDS is a constant declared in the django.forms.models module, can you check the file in your server?

Comment: @Alvaro I have updated the OP with the file as it is on the server

Comment: Is this a bug in the lasted zinnia install?

Comment: I'm guessing a problem with django.. try running a python shell on your server and importing django.forms.ALL_FIELDS and django.forms.models.ALL_FIELDS. If it fails, there is something wrong with the django installation

Comment: I just tried: import django.forms.ALL_FIELDS and got No module named ALL_FIELDS. I have uninstall and reinstalled Django and still the same. everything else works 'Django wise' tho. On my working locally version  import django.forms.ALL_FIELDS also states not found

Comment: My bad, I just gave you the full constant path, the correct sintax would be: from django.forms import ALL_FIELDS   <and>    from django.forms.models import ALL_FIELDS         - Sorry for making that mistake

Comment: @Alvaro from django.forms import ALL_FIELDS still give me ImportError: cannot import name ALL_FIELDS. However, I have tried the same on my local instance too and I get the same message but the app works! very strange. Does the statement work for you?

Comment: I then tried on an instance using Django 1.6 can the same. I created a new box (just to test) on www.nitrous.io with their standard Django set again from django.forms import ALL_FIELDS gives an error see OP update

Answer (score 1):

Zinnia v0.14 is not compatible with django 1.5

http://docs.django-blog-zinnia.com/en/latest/notes/compatibility.html